# Javascript getElementbyID with button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

EDIT: I have fixed the semi-colons, the case sensitivity, as well as the brackets. The code WORKS if I remove the functions after `buttonPARTICULAR`! Why?

EDIT: Fixed. I'm a dumbass. Sorry!!! :-Z

When I keep it simple, like this, everything works fine:

```
  <head>
  <script>

     function buttonGRUPO()
     {
         document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="Grupo";
     }
     function buttonPARTICULAR()
     {
         document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="Particular";
     }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <p>&nbsp;<button class="art-button" onclick="buttonPARTICULAR()">Aulas Particulares</button></p>
    <p>&nbsp;<button class="art-button" onclick="buttonGRUPO()">Aulas em Grupo</button></p>
  <p id="desc">Text</p>
 </body>
```

However, whenever I add more functions to the script, ALL of the buttons and code stop working.

```
 <head>
 <script>

function buttonGRUPO()
{
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="Grupo";
}
function buttonPARTICULAR()
{
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="Particular";
}
function buttonINCOMPANY()
{
    document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="in-COmpany";
}
function buttonINTENSIVOS()
}
    document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="Intensivo";
{
function buttonIMERSIVOS()
}
    document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="Imersivos"
{
function buttonPALESTRAS()
}
    document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="Palestras"
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
 <p>&nbsp;<button class="art-button" onclick="buttonPARTICULAR()">Aulas Particulares</button></p>
 <p>&nbsp;<button class="art-button" onclick="buttonGRUPO()">Aulas em Grupo</button>  </p>
 <p id="desc">Text</p>
 </body>
```

How is it that augmenting the quantity of virtually identical code will disrupt even the code that, before, was functional? Am I committing a syntax error here?

EDIT

@Woot4Moot Still not functional

still not functional.

```
function buttonB()
 {
document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="B";
}
function buttonA()
{
document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="A";
}
function buttonC()
{
document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="C";
}
function buttonD()
{
document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="D";
}
function buttonE()
{
document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="E";
}
function buttonF()
{
 document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="F";
}

<p><button onclick="buttonA()">A</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="buttonB()">B</button></p>
<p id="desc"> text</p>'
```

To be more specific, when I load this code into my browser (the buttons and `p id="desc"`) but when the buttons are clicked on, the `p id="desc"` does not change according to the JavaScript command.

Comment: tags should be updated to reflect the more general `javascript` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the syntax errors:

```
function buttonINTENSIVOS()
}
document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="Intensivo"
{
function buttonIMERSIVOS()
}
document.getElementbyID("desc").innerHTML="Imersivos"
{
function buttonPALESTRAS()
}
```

Your braces are the wrong way.  Functions open with `{` not `}` and you dont have semicolons `;` to terminate each command

What you want is this:

```
function buttonINTENSIVOS()
  {
    document.getElementbyId("desc").innerHTML="Intensivo";
  }
function buttonIMERSIVOS()
{
      document.getElementbyId("desc").innerHTML="Imersivos";
}
function buttonPALESTRAS()
{  ... }
```

Comment: Also missing the semi-colons

Comment: @Woot4Moo Your braces are still backwards.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName there I go with my quick typing.  Fixed.

Comment: @AndÚ updated again, it seems you changed from `getElementById` to `getElementByID`

Answer (score 1):

As well as what has already been pointed out (incorrect opening/closing braces), javascript is case sensitive, so your method name is incorrect:

```
document.getElementbyID("...")
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("....")
```

(note the lower-case `d` in `Id` and the uppercase `B` in `By`)

Comment: @AndÚ - see update - you had 2 case irregularities in the method name, not 1 as originally posted!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make this neater and easier to debug, I would suggest using the following function to condense the individual functions into one:

```
function button(letter)
{
  document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML=letter;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<p><button onclick="button('A')">A</button></p>
<p><button onclick="button('B')">B</button></p>
<p><button onclick="button('C')">C</button></p>

<p id="desc"></p>
```

Note the single quotes inside each of the brackets. The function will directly print the contents of the brackets to the **p id=desc**.